# How to create a batch file to map network drives after connected to VPN

Tags: batch-file, networking, network-drive

What is the best method for creating a batch file (.bat) that will automatically map network drives after a internet connection has been established. The batch file will be remain in the windows start up folder and will only map the network drives if they are not already mapped. I have tried the following:

```
:Start
ping -n 1 www.google.com

If %errorlevel% == 0 Goto :Start

If %errorlevel% == 1 Goto :Connected

:Connected

Net Use F:\\ Server\Folder /Persistent:No
```

The ping reply is so fast that the Net use command doesn't map the drive even though the path is correct and will work if I manually enter the net use and path in the CMD window. I need for it to wait after the ping reply and then map the network drives and also for it to only map the network drives if they are not already mapped. I realize what I have tried doesn't address the "only map the network drives if they are not already mapped". I have done some extensive searching and I cannot find the answer to these issues. Would appreciate step by step and easy to follow instructions for resolving this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you connect to VPN ? most VPN client give possibility to execute scripts once connection is done. Your batch file should go here

Comment: I want to try and accomplish this task locally using a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe additional "timeout" can help?

updated

I use windows vpn client.
To check available connection i make script like this
and wait 30 second before check by ping.
And i ping my server which available only under vpn.

```
@echo off
set myserver=192.168..
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rasdial FirstVPN /disconnect
rasdial SecondVPN /disconnect

echo ==== second vpn
start rasdial SecondVPN
timeout /T 30
for /f "Tokens=*" %%G in ('ping -n 1 %myserver% ^| FIND "TTL="') do set ans="%%G"
IF NOT [%ans%]==[] GOTO Connected

echo ==== first vpn
start rasdial FirstVPN
timeout /T 30
for /f "Tokens=*" %%G in ('ping -n 1 %myserver% ^| FIND "TTL="') do set ans="%%G"
IF [%ans%]==[] (exit)
:Connected
echo %ans%
```

Comment: Timeout /T10 makes it go in a loop after the time runs out.

Comment: I am impressed ! you don't know what his VPN client is and you post an answer ! any crystal ball in here ? :)